# How to backup a server with large files

Tags: server, backup

I have a dedicated server and I'd like to make a back up and migrate it to another shared server, but it seems like the data it contains is too large to be transferred to my local computer. This is what I get when I run `df -h`:

| Filesystem | Size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/mapper/vg_d153-lv_root | 50G | 28G | 19G | 60% | / |
| tmpfs | 7.8G | 0 | 7.8G | 0% | /dev/shm |
| /dev/sda1 | 477M | 110M | 343M | 25% | /boot |
| /dev/mapper/vg_d153-lv_home | 99G | 13G | 82G | 14% | /home |
| /dev/mapper/vg_d153-var | 701G | 442G | 225G | 67% | /var |
| /dev/mapper/vg_d153-backup | 701G | 652G | 14G | 99% | /backup |

What are those huge files? Do I need them?

There are a few webpress websites, a database (less than 1gb, already did the backup).

How should I handle this backup properly?